# Getting rid of loaded assemblies

Tags: c#, process, runtime, assemblies

I made a script tool using the .NET integrated compiler.

Shortly, at runtime it compiles a source file to a assembly, creates a object defined in the assembly and starts a method of the object.

Here's the code (heavily simplified):

```
CodeDomProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
// ...
CompilerResults res = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, source);
// ...
return res.CompiledAssembly;
```

This can happen multiple times during the tool is running.
So far so good, it's working great.

**Problem:**
The compiled assembly is loaded into my process, the debugger tells me this:

```
'ScriptTool.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'v7wyfy7w', No symbols loaded.
```

This happens every time i 'run' a script. So after a while, there are a lot of assemblies loaded into the process, killing memory.

**Now the question is:**
Is it possible to *unload* the assemblies?

Comment: Unloading assemblies requires using a separate AppDomain.  Well covered in .NET literature.

Comment: @HansPassant: Can you give me some links?

Comment: Here's a start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s0z09xw.aspx

Comment: So when i'm creating a new AppDomain, am i able to call a object's method from the main AppDomain?

Comment: Use google for links.  Query "load and unload assemblies in appdomain".

Comment: @joe, yes, you can, but it's not a walk in the park.  You'll need to delve into some marshalling/serialization and ensure that the touchpoints between appdomains is minimized as much as possible.